# R data frame string contains: Does column 1 contain column 2?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, contains

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
  Surname                Email
1   house  greghouse@gmail.com
2  wilson johnwatson@gmail.com
```

I want to create a logical vector which checks if `Surname` is contained in `Email`. The result should therefore be:

```
  Surname                Email CheckEmail
1   house  greghouse@gmail.com       TRUE
2  wilson johnwatson@gmail.com      FALSE
```

I tried `grep` but it seems that `grep` can only look for one pattern in 1 or more instances. **I specifically need to look for multiple patterns in multiple instances**.

```
> grep(df1$Surname,df1$Email)
[1] 1
Warning message:
In grep(df1$Surname, df1$Email) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `library("stringi")` and:

```
df1$CheckEmail <- stri_detect_fixed(df1$Email, df1$Surname)
```

Comment: Why do you need dplyr for this?

Comment: Because `stringi` can't manage two vectors one to one in this case and `dplyr` allows that. And it creates a new column at the same time, so there's no need of `cbind` later.

Comment: Does `dat$CheckEmail <- with(dat, stri_detect_fixed(Email,Surname))` not work?

Comment: Additional packages should be used for a reason. Here, the use of `stringi` (or its wrapper `stringr` with the `str_detect` function) makes sense, while the use of `dplyr` has no purpose, since the same simple operation (adding a column to a `data.frame`) can be obviously made in `base` R.

Comment: It works. But I didn't knew `with` function before. I suppose the logic is similar to `dplyr` here, because `stri_detect_fixed(dat$Email,dat$Surname)` doesn't work. `with` function is simpler, so it's better, I agree.

Comment: What you mean with `doesn't work`? That line works, and it is equivalent to `with(dat, stri_detect_fixed(Email,Surname))`. The `with` function is unnecessary, it's just sugar. The most basic version is `dat$CheckEmail <- stri_detect_fixed(dat$Email,dat$Surname)`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. I made a mistake in my code while typing this simple `stri_detect_fixed`, that is why it didn't work. Thanks for your note. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Keep your answer, since the `stringi` bit is useful. Just delete the `dplyr` part and edit accordingly.

Comment: @nicola exactly. I used with for readability (habit from using too long names for dataframes).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a base R approach using `mapply` with `grepl`:

```
transform(df, CheckEmail = mapply(grepl, Surname, Email))
#  Surname                Email CheckEmail
#1   house  greghouse@gmail.com       TRUE
#2  wilson johnwatson@gmail.com      FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a base R option using `Vectorize` with `grepl`:

```
df1$CheckEmail <- Vectorize(grepl)(df1$Surname, df1$Email)
```

Comment: I shall keep `Vectorize` in mind - seems useful.  Is it faster than using `vapply`?

Comment: @Bazz It is very readable, but it's not going to do you any favors as far as performance goes.