# R: delete a substring from a string on a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing the mark and the name of many products as follows:

```
    mark      name
    Caudalie  Caudalie Eau démaquillante 200ml
    Mustela   Mustela Bébé lait hydra corps 300ml
    Lierac    Lierac Phytolastil gel prévention
```

In many rows, the mark exist in the product name. What I want to do is to detect if the mark exists in the product name, If so  I want to remove It.

**Edit:**
I used this sample of code to detect if the mark exists in the product name:

```
   df1$CheckMark <- Vectorize(grepl)(df1$mark, df1$name)
```

My dataframe looks like this now:

```
    mark      name                                ChekMark
    Caudalie  Caudalie Eau démaquillante 200ml    TRUE
    Mustela   Mustela Bébé lait hydra corps 300ml TRUE
    Lierac    Lierac Phytolastil gel prévention   TRUE
```

I want to subset the mark from the product name.

**UPDATE**
After many attempts. I switched my big dataframe to a list according to the mark:

```
    list.mark.name=split( df1 , df1$mark )
```

And I found this awesome combination between `sapply` and `gsub`:

```
    listt<-sapply(1:length(list.marque.nom), function(i)
    {
     dtfr<-list.marque.nom[[i]]
      if(dtfr$CheckMark==TRUE)
     {listt[[i]]<-as.data.frame(sapply(dtfr,gsub,pattern=dtfr$mark,replacement=""))}
      else
     {listt[[i]]<-dtfr} 
     }
```

I thought that everything is okey but I noticed these warnings:

```
     Warning messages:
     1: In if (dtfr$CheckMark == TRUE) { ... :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What's the problem please.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've tried already, i.e. post some of the code?

Comment: In the updated example, there is no `mark`?

Comment: Actually Yes. I used `mark` as example

Comment: This is probably some type of a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365768/using-grep-to-subset-rows-from-a-data-table-comparing-row-content/31366411) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717733/r-data-frame-string-contains-does-column-1-contain-column-2/)

Answer (score 1):

If we need to subset the rows by removing the "name" elements that starts with 'mark', then use `grep`

```
df1[!grepl('^mark', df1$name),]
```

The `^` signifies the start of the string.

NOTE: The `subtract` part in the title is not clear.

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset, if we want to check 'name' that doesn't have a matching substring in any of the 'mark' elements, we can `paste` the 'mark' elements together and use `grep` to get the index and then subset with `[`,

```
df1[!grepl(paste(df1$mark, collapse="|"), df1$name),]
```

Or if the idea is to subset rows based on corresponding elements of 'name', 'mark',  `stri_detect` from `stringi` is an option.

```
library(stringi)
df1[!stri_detect_fixed(df1$name, df1$mark),]
```

Comment: @user5779182  Check if the update helps.

Comment: `df1[!grepl(paste(df1$mark, collapse="|"), df1$name),]` will also remove a row where there is a mark-name from a different row - not sure if this is desired

Comment: @docendodiscimus  As the OP didn't show the expected result, I added both options.  The `stringi` should work on each row.

Comment: @akrun . It's okey for the `grepl` function : I used this sample of code `df1$CheckMark <- Vectorize(grepl)(df1$mark, df1$name)` . I want now to remove the mark from the product name. Any idea ?

Comment: @user5779182  You can try `sub(paste0("(", paste(df1$mark, collapse="|"), ")\\s*"), "", df1$name)`

Comment: @akrun I tried your solution but I got this error: `Error in sub(paste0("(", paste(df1$mark, collapse = "|"),  : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634`

Comment: @user5779182 I am not sure what is going at your end.  It works perfectly fine with the example posted.  I am using `stringi_1.0-1`

Comment: @akrun I think the problem is because my dataframe is too big. I edited my question. Have you any idea ? Thank you

Comment: @user5779182  I think the `stringi` should still work on big datasets as it is very efficient.

Comment: @akrun , switching `sapply` by `mapply` resolved the problem :

`df1=as.data.frame(mapply(gsub,df1$mark,"",df1$name))`. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: @sarah Thank you for the feedback.